# [VS MAC]Updating to .NET 8 all of my Maui projects display Error NETSDK1139: The target platform identifier ios was not recognized

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, maui, visual-studio-mac

Yesterday I updated from .NET 7.0 to .NET 8.0 following my colleague doing so and having it work immediately. For myself however, on both my VS Mac and my VS Windows I get the error

> Error NETSDK1139: The target platform identifier ios was not recognized.

[image]

(This error also appears in the android variant if set to ios as the deploy target)

The target frameworks are listed as net8.0-android;net8.0-ios;

[image]

I've all of the following~

- Uninstalling all .NET SDKs and Workloads, as well as VS 2022
- Reinstalling only VS 2022 and .NET 8 (.NET 6 and 7 being automatically installed with VS)
- Running command line statements such as dotnet workload restore and install for maui, maui-ios and maui-android.
- A brand new Maui project
- I've also attempted to get maui-check working but it seems entirely busted at the moment with errors such as 'zsh: killed     maui-check'.

It's also worth noting that~

- When creating a new maui project .NET 8 is not an option, only .NETs 7 and 6
- I don't have any simulators or devices appearing as deploy targets since updating.

[image]

- My .NET core and runtimes are listed both in VS 2022 and when running command lines to check which are installed on the system.

[image]

I would really appreciate anyone's knowledge on this subject and especially anyone who has previously encountered and dealt with this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same issue and the following is what fixed it,

- Make sure you have the preview feature on your Mac

[image]

- Also make sure that you have the SDK https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/8.0
- Also in my case, I had to reinstall VS MAC (Only do this if needed)

Comment: This was it, thank you for this!
I did have some luck getting Android building by installing the x64 (rather than Arm64) Packages, it seems the Arm64 packages are somewhat lacking in everything they need, but this is the fix people will need!

Comment: To anyone reviewing this that also needs to install the x64 packages, also make sure that you restart your mac after installation.

Comment: This fixed the issue of not being able to select an emulator

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information to provide you just right details to fix but these things I would check first:

- Do you have latest version of VS?
- Do you have other versions of VS?
- Check if you have other workloads.

Check open issues with similar problem. Like there was an issue reported some time ago on github - https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/1795

Comment: Thanks for the response, the solution was to enable .NET 8 in preview features.

Answer (score 0):

I had this NETSDK1139 problem with my command line build script, and realized I needed to switch from **msbuild** to **dotnet build**. I was able to build the app otherwise in Visual Studio 2022 IDE, but not with msbuild. The vstool had replaced mdtool with Visual Studio 2017. A switch to msbuild to replace vstool was necessary with Visual Studio 2022. Now finally dotnet.