# Step into external code in Visual Studio (.NET MAUI Android)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, maui

I'm trying to step into code of referenced libraries in my .NET MAUI Android project, but can't get it to work.
I did the following:

- Install the latest version of VS
- Disable "Just my Code" in settings
- Enable Symbol Servers in settings
- Create a new .NET 8 MAUI project
- Add `Console.WriteLine()` to the MainPage constructor and set a breakpoint on that line
- Start Debugging on Android Emulator
- When the breakpoint is hit, perform "Step into"

Results:

- VS still shows the MainPage.xaml.cs
- `Console.WriteLine()` is the active frame in the Callstack view
- The option "Go to Source" is not available on that frame
- The status of "System.Private.CoreLib.dll" (Assembly that contains System.Console) in the Modules View is "Symbols loaded"

So what am I missing? Why is the source code of System.Console not showing?
Btw: When debugging on WinUI, the source code loads as expected.

Comment: Is this VS MAC?

Comment: no its VS for Windows. VS Mac doesn't support .NET8 unfortunately. VS Code for Mac has the same issue.

Comment: VS Mac does support .NET 8, I use it every day, its gonna get deprecated in 6 months though, Anyway I will check this in my windows over the weekend and respond if this works or not

Comment: yes, you are right, it has "preview" support for .NET 8. But I was not able to start a .NET 8 MAUI Android App with it. ... Thank you.

Comment: Check this maybe it would help https://stackoverflow.com/a/77518683/7462031